# Error in numpy array assignment

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to upload 17 images into a 4d numpy array, each image size is (256,256,1), so basically I'm using the 0th dimension for collection of different images. Following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
test_ip=np.zeros(shape=(17, 256, 256, 1))
count=0
for img in image_generator1:
  test_ip[count,:,:,:]=img
  count+=1
```

But it outputs an error:

> IndexError: index 17 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 17

Also I printed shape of img in for loop and instead of `(256,256,1)` it is `(1,256,256,1)`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of your `test_ip` array goes from 0 to 16. So 17 is indeed too big (out of bounds).

You could add a try/except:

```
for counter, img in enumerate(image_generator1):
    try:
        test_ip[counter] = img
    except IndexError as err:
        print(f"Filled the array with {counter + 1} images")    # f-string requires >= python 3.6
```

Or if you know the length of that generator, just use this:

```
test_ip = np.array([im for im in image_generator1])
```

Comment: +1 for explaining to OP the error! Just curious, why do we need to know the generators length? We can avoid it for sure, right for making the code dynamic, isn't?

Comment: If you don't know the generator length, you won't know for sure that (in this case) the final array has 17 as its first dimension. You will always need to try except to ensure you don't overshoot that value. And you cannot know the generator's length if you only have the object - you'd need to know how it was created. Also, generators can actually grow while they are being consumed; think e.g. of streaming live tweets via a generator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @n1k31t4. I've a small doubt: since image_generator_1 has 17 images the loop runs 17 times so count will never index into 17 in it's 0 axis

Comment: Indexing starts at 0 (not with 1) so the image insertion into the array will work, and all 17 images of the generator will be consumed. Please see the updated code, which corrects the print message.